# Why must the stack VMA be executable?

Tags: kernel, process, memory, stack

I am currently reading *Linux Kernel Development* by Robert Love.

In the chapter "15 The Process Address Space" he prints the memory map of a process.

```
user@machine:~$ pmap 1424
#all the processes mapped memory (skipped for readability)
bfffe000 (8KB)        rwxp (0:00 0)         [ stack ]
```

The last line shows the stack (as it grows down).
He now states:

> The stack is, naturally, readable, writeable and executable - not of much use otherwise.

As far as I know we use the stack for data and code addresses (functions and their parameters/variable).

I do not understand why the stack must be executable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That information is outdated, and the stack is typically not executable any more:

```
00007ffd884fa000    356K rw---   [ stack ]
```

GCC needs an executable stack if it generates [trampolines for nested function calls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Trampolines.html). These trampolines are small pieces of code generated at runtime, and stored on the stack — so if they are used, the stack needs to be executable. The compiler keeps track of this requirement, and it outputs a flag in binaries (libraries and executables) to indicate whether they need an executable stack. You can see and manipulate the value of this flag using [`execstack(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/execstack.8.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not have access to a linux machine since I read the chapter and it was really bugging me.

Comment: On the other hand, inner functions are being used more and more. It's better code.